# Forward Google Calendar invites to another account

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to forward a Google Calendar invite sent to my work email (either before or after I have confirmed that I will attend) to my private Google Calendar?

I get invites to meetings emailed to my work email (which has no Gmail association at all). Right now I have to copy the information by hand if I want to get it transferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Google Calendar invitations cannot be forwarded via email." - why, and how to workaround?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11721/google-calendar-invitations-cannot-be-forwarded-via-email-why-and-how-to-w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has the ics file attached to the email, then you could import it into Google:  http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37118

Answer (score 1):

## Click "Add to calendar" link

There's also an add to calendar button link below event details. This will let you add the event to an alternate Google Calendar/Account.

This is same as using the .ics file attached to the invite email.

> Note: yyou will not be able to RSVP using this method.

Comment: Where is this "Add to calendar" link? I can't find it https://i.imgur.com/Rv3kwIE.png