# "Google Calendar invitations cannot be forwarded via email." - why, and how to workaround?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-calendar

Several people in my organisation get this message in the following set up:

1. x@institution.edu (using Google apps) forwards everything to y@gmail.com
2. Someone invites x@institution.edu
3. While logged in under y@gmail.com, they open the email and click "Yes" (or No or Maybe).

Some of us actually have a third layer, z@organisation.org, which is not a mailbox, but just forwards everything to x@institution.edu, and people sometimes send calendar invitations to that address. (Not sure if this is relevant).

They can instead do "Add to calendar", but that means the original sender doesn't get an attendance update.

There is very little information on this message on the web, so I think this must not be a general policy.

I would love to know:

1. Does anyone have a set up like the above that *doesn't* have this problem?
2. Is there anything we can do about it? Any suggested workaround?

Comment: You're not alone

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=41cad053f56707a2&hl=en

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, just right-click "Yes" (or No or Maybe), and choose 'open link in incognito window'. This is a way to let the sender know whether you are attending, without adding the event to your gmail Calendar.

Comment: Really interesting idea - sorry I didn't see this earlier, or when it was still relevant. (I'm not at the place with Google Apps anymore.)

Comment: After trying the "google" way several times, including going through official tutorials that aren't even up to date with Google's web apps... this method actually works!

Comment: Heh, thanks. Just shy of 6 years late. :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work now, or do you have to be logged into Chrome-?

Answer (score 2):

If you get an invite to x@institution.edu, that invite will be added to the calendar of x@institution.edu. There are a couple of options, if you want to never open you institution.edu apps account:

[Share your @institution.edu calendar](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37084) with your y@gmail.com account. If you allow your y@gmail to edit the manage the calendar, you'll be able to reply 'Yes' to the invite while signed into your Gmail account.

Note that the domain administrator can control sharing options for your calendar, and may not let a non-domain (you y@gmail.com address) get to share and edit events in the calendar of x@institution.edu. You'll have to have a chat with the apps admin if that's a case.

Alternatively, you could get people to send invites directly to your Gmail account.

Comment: >Share your @institution.edu calendar with your y@gmail.com account. 

Yeah, that's the Google line. One huge downside is that it means everyone ends up with two calendars they need to share with everyone. If you want to see whether I can come to a meeting, you need to check both steve@gmail and steve@institution.

Comment: I separate my personal and work calendars. If something needs to be added to both of them, I just add my personal email to a work invitation. I don't really want all my events visible to everyone at work. They don't need to know what I'm doing over the weekend or in the evenings.

Comment: FWIW (not much, I think), I tend to use my "personal" calendar for work, and have a separate calendar that I share with my partner for personal stuff. (Highly recommended - never double book each other again!)