# How can I respond to Google Calendar invitations from my alternate email?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have two separate mailboxes setup with Gmail: 'emailA@gmail.com' which is available publicly, and emailB@gmail.com which I keep private.

Any email invitations sent to emailA@gmail.com are auto-forwarded to emailB@gmail.com. However, when I try to accept an invitation, I am unable to accept it.

[image: "Ooops! It looks like you're trying to access this event using emailB@gmail.com"]

Note that, while similar, this is not the same issue as [*“Google Calendar invitations cannot be forwarded via email.”*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/11721/60818), as that applies to forwarding invites between emails hosted by different organizations. (x@company.edu vs y@gmail.com)

I would like to avoid using the "Add to calendar" button, as it does not send notifications to the event organizer that I have RSVP'd.

**How can I setup Gmail to let me accept Google Calendar invitations from my alternate email?**

Comment: @pnuts [Google's help articles say this is possible](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37135), but the directions are inconsistent and don't seem to be working properly. I'll update if I get this working.

Answer (score 10):

Google's instructions for this are inconsistent and split across a few different articles: [Set up an alternate email](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347), and [allow responding to events from an alternate email](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37135), etc.

I've adapted and consolidated Google's official instructions below, but bizzarly **their instructions only seem to work with non-Google email addresses** (@hotmail, @yahoo, etc)

Important notes:

- This will ***not*** work for accounts hosted through work, school, or other organizations. (x@company.org, y@school.edu) (*see [Google Calendar invitations cannot be forwarded via email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11721/google-calendar-invitations-cannot-be-forwarded-via-email-why-and-how-to-w)*)
- The settings for responding to forwarded email invitations ***will be hidden*** if you have not set up an alternate email address.

> #### [Setting up an alternate email](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347)
>
> 1. Sign in to [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. In the "Personal info & privacy" section, select **Your personal info**.
> 3. Choose **Email**.
> 4. Select **Alternate emails**.
> 5. If asked, verify your current username and password.
> 6. Select either **Add alternate email** or **Add other email**. Enter an email address you own and select **Add**.

> #### [Allow forwarding from your alternate address](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37135)
>
> 1. On your computer, open [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/).
> 2. In the top right, click Settings [image] → **Settings**.
> 3. Select your primary calendar from the left-hand **Settings for my calendars** menu.
> 4. Find the **General notifications** section.
> 5. Check the box for **Allow responding to invitations forwarded through alternative email addresses**. Note, it may take a little while after adding an alternate email for this setting to appear.
>
> After you turn on this setting, you can use your Google Account to
>   respond to event invitations forwarded from your alternate email
>   address. Event responses will display as coming from your Google
>   Account, not the alternate email address which was originally invited
>   to the event.

Comment: `Event responses will display as coming from your Google Account, not the alternate email address which was originally invited to the event.` — This is the problem. I want the response to be seen as coming from the alternate email address.

Comment: @ayjay this is exactly my use case. Have you managed to find a solution yet?

Answer (score 7):

In the new Google Calendar settings interface, the requisite "respond to forwarded events" setting described by [Stevoisiak's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/108851/60818) is found under the **General Notifications** category of settings accessed by selecting your main calendar in the left-side menu.

*Note, it can take some time before the setting shows up in GCal after you've added and verified your alternate email address.*

[image: General notifications]

Comment: How long before the changes take effect? I followed the steps and checked the tick box. However, when i sent an outlook calendar invite test, the response being sent back is still from my gmail account and not the alternate email.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not seem to find the option. The options from the screenshot are now under `Other notifications`, but the checkbox option is not to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick method is to right click on the Yes, Maybe, or No link and select "Copy Link address". Then, in another browser logged into the other Alternate e-mail address account, paste the URL into a new tab.
[image: Right Click on Yes, Maybe, or No and Copy Link Address]

Answer (score 0):

Google's instructions are not only inconsistent but incorrect in some cases. I have been using gmail since 2005 or 2006, got my gmail address, and later added an alternate address from my German GMX domain to my google account.

When I tried to follow the instructions, I found out that there is no such option "allow responding to invitations forwarded through alternative email addresses" in my settings.

To solve the problem, I have filed a Google calendar support issue here:
[How to prevent 404 error in gsuite calendar when accepting ics invitation sent to my alternate @gmx.](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/99074994).

Please note that I have to post this as an answer, as I have no capability to post comments in the webapps stackexchange yet, so please consider this before downvoting. I plan to update my answer once my case will be successfully solved!

Update: Turns out one year later that there was another distinct Google account for my other email address that I must have created sometime. After deleting that other account, it was possible to add the alternative email so that I can now fully use it for Google calendar.